# 'knife: command not found' after chef-server installation

Tags: chef-infra

Im learning chef. I have setup couple of centos 6.4 vms. On one of the VMs(say chef-server), installed chef-server-core-12.6.0-1.el5.x86_64.rpm, server front-end, reconfigured chef-server-ctl and chef-manage-ctl and setup user & org. I downloaded `starter kit` from front end and extracted chef-repo folder on chef-server vm. 
Here is my problem. Based on the tutorial i'm following, I should be able to run `knife ssl fetch` from chef-repo folder. But, I am facing `knife: command not found` error. I tried googling but could find the an exact reason. What am I missing!! Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's "the tutorial" that you are following?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chef repo and the starter kit, together with [ChefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk) does *not* belong to the server, but to the *workstation*, aka. your laptop.

`knife` is included and ChefDK and used to communicate with the Chef Server.

EDIT: Actually, I think the [Chef Components](https://docs.chef.io/chef_overview.html#chef-components) section of the official documentation provides a good overview.

---

*Not sure, which tutorial you are following - the official one is on [learn.chef.io](https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/). Does that provide clear guidance?*

Comment: StephenKing, Thank you for correcting my rookie mistake. I was following steps of a workshop. I will switch to learn.chef.io.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct using the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar errors while trying to run knife related commands. I restarted the windows 2012, and then I was able to run these commands. Try this.